# How do I parse a variable from my Visualforce Page URL to my Visualforce email template?

Tags: visualforce, email, email-template

I need to get a string into my Visualforce email template. I have attempted to parse it over the URL as I thought it would be the easiest way but I'm not sure.  I am using sendMail and sending the email with a controller so If I can call the string in the Visualforce template that would work too.  Any advice?

Here is my string.

```
String ProteusStaffName = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('VFname');
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer to this is "can't be done."

Answer (score 1):

Make your string variable public and define getter and setter:

```
public String ProteusStaffName {get; private set;}
```

then in your constructor or your init method set it's value

```
public YourClassConstructor()
{
    String ProteusStaffName = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('VFname');
}
```

And now it's easy to reference it on the visualforce page:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!ProteusStaffName}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether it would work in this context I don't know, but there is a direct way to get page parameters in Visualforce:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!$CurrentPage.Parameters.VFName}"/>
```